# Why do some players get starting trade goods in 7 player TI3?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

In 7 player Twilight Imperium there are 3 starting positions that get trade goods at the beginning of the game.  The position that gets 6 trade goods is obviously worse than the others. The two that get 4 don't seem worse than their adjacent starting positions. What is different about them, that they require the bonus trade goods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position 3, which gets the 6 trade goods is, as you say, clearly the worst, all cramped up there.

The two which get 4 trade goods, positions 1 & 2, only have 3 tiles which are directly connected to their home world, whereas the remaining 4 positions are connected to the board with 4 tiles. This gives them more movement options and I guess this would be why the others are compensated :)